# getting incorrect address of a variable during a function call

Tags: c

I am losing the address of a (global) variable (defined in a shared object) when a function call is made. To prove it, I intentionally set the value of the variable num_accounts to 55, when the function get_num_accounts() began the execution, the pointer to this variable was received incorrectly. My proof is this gdb session:

```
accounts_init () at accounts.c:31
31      err_code=read_accounts();
(gdb) print num_accounts
$1 = 0
(gdb) print &num_accounts
$2 = (account_idx_t *) 0x7ffff767c640 <num_accounts>
(gdb) set var num_accounts=55
(gdb) print num_accounts
$3 = 55
(gdb) s
read_accounts () at accounts.c:66
66      err_code=get_num_accounts(&num_accounts);
(gdb) s
get_num_accounts (num_accounts_ptr=0x604780 <num_accounts>) at accounts.c:119
119     *num_accounts_ptr=0;
(gdb) print num_accounts
$4 = 55
(gdb) print *num_accounts_ptr
$5 = 0
(gdb) 
(gdb) print num_accounts_ptr
$6 = (account_idx_t *) 0x604780 <num_accounts>
(gdb)
```

The address of the variable num_accounts is **0x7ffff767c640** , but I get **0x604780** when the function is executed, why such a weird stuff happens ?

The source code of the function **get_num_accounts()** is this:

```
err_code_t get_num_accounts(account_idx_t *num_accounts_ptr) {
    err_code_t err_code;
    uint32_t file_size;
    div_t div_result;
    unsigned short number;

    *num_accounts_ptr=0;
    err_code=get_dir();
    if (err_code!=ERR_NO_ERROR) return err_code;
    err_code=get_file(ACCOUNTS_FILENAME,sizeof(ACCOUNTS_FILENAME),&file_size);
    if (err_code!=ERR_NO_ERROR) return err_code;

    div_result=div(file_size,sizeof(tbl_account_t));
    if (div_result.rem!=0) {
        return ERR_BAD_CONFIG_FILE_FORMAT;
    }
    number=div_result.quot;
    *num_accounts_ptr=number;
    return ERR_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Type account_idx_t is defined as:

```
typedef         unsigned short          account_idx_t;
```

The global variable num_accounts is defined in accounts.c file at the beginning:

```
account_idx_t       num_accounts=0;
```

Basically, what the function does, is to get the size of the file and calculate the number of records that the file contains, before reading it. (its a database)

And this is the calling code, which calles get_num_accounts() function:

```
err_code_t accounts_init(void) {
    err_code_t err_code;

    err_code=read_accounts();
    if (err_code!=ERR_NO_ERROR) return err_code;

    return ERR_NO_ERROR;
}
err_code_t read_accounts(void) {
    err_code_t err_code;
    int ret;

    err_code=get_num_accounts(&num_accounts);
    if (err_code!=ERR_NO_ERROR) return err_code;
    if (num_accounts==0) return ERR_NO_ERROR;

    int fd=open(filename_buf,O_RDONLY); // filename_buf is global, it holds filename from previous call
    if (fd==-1) {
        return ERR_SYS_ERROR;
    }
    ret=read(fd,accounts,sizeof(tbl_account_t)*num_accounts);
    if (ret==-1) {
        return ERR_SYS_ERROR;
    }
    ret=close(fd);  // TO_DO: validate return value of close(fd)
    if (ret==-1) {
        return ERR_SYS_ERROR;
    }
    return ERR_NO_ERROR;
}
```

I am compiling the library with -fPIC flag:

```
[niko@dev1 src]$ make accounts.o
gcc -g -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused -Winline -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wformat -D_GNU_SOURCE -fshort-enums -fPIC -c accounts.c
```

There is no another 'num_accounts' symbol anywhere in the source code, I double checked that:

```
[niko@dev1 src]$ nm *o|grep num_accounts 
0000000000000000 T get_num_accounts
0000000000000000 B num_accounts
[niko@dev1 src]$
```

Any suggestion on further debugging steps?

Comment: I am not good at GDB. So might be a silly question. Are you stepping into `get_num_accounts` or stepping over. If you are stepping over by the time you are reading `*num_accounts_ptr` it is out of scope.

Comment: @MotKohn stepping into it , with the 's' command, to step over it is the command 'n'

Comment: Sorry for asking again but 0x7ffff767c640 does not look like a valid address to me. A little too high, isn't it?

Comment: @MotKohn yes, but it is a shared object, it has a different (virtual) address  space, could be different from the data segment of the main program afaik

Comment: There is no malloc() in my code, all variables are statically allocated, so, no bugs of that type are possible

Comment: If you could provide a short compilable example that people can actually compile and run and reproduce the problem, it would be a lot easier for folks to help.

Comment: Moreover -- why would you every expect a variable to have the same address on two successive runs of a program? That isn't something you have control over, that's up to your OS memory manager. You also cannot draw any correlation between addresses assigned within GDB and without it. GDB uses isn't own buffers to aid in debugging that are not present when you run your code outside GDB.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths , I have made such short compilable example, but it works fine, the address of the global variable remains the same. In my code it is replaced by another address during the call. I do not use mallocs, but maybe I overwrote something in my code and the address of the variable somehow changed ??? If you tell me where to debug or how, that will solve this issue. But I dont know where too look.

Comment: The point isn't to say you *can't* get the same address back, the point is that you have no guarantee of it happening.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , I have made a short example of a function call passing a global variable, and debugged it with GDB, the address does not change, so GDB is fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , the  GDB session posted in the question description is a single run.

Comment: I just ran the program without GDB and it runs fine. the num_accounts is set correctly as the data was read from file. It is only when I step through the program with the debugger I see "bugs". I ran valgrind on my program too, nothing bad was reported. Maybe I found a bug in GDB ???

Comment: I believe I do have a bug despite that the program runs fine, it just doesn't show up. The variable num_accounts is declared in the code that compiles as a shared library and is loaded at runtime. The only way I fixed it is by moving the num_accounts variable from the library code into the main application code. This was the fix. But I yet do not understand why referencing a global variable declared inside shared library causes this problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I have made a short compilable example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394971/can-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-a-shared-library

Comment: Can you compile your program with `--warn-common` linker flag?

Comment: @RomanKhimov thanks for the tip! however, adding -Wl,--warn-common produced no warnings

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct symbols called `num_accounts` in the executable image that gdb is looking at.  gdb tells you that directly, as whenever you tell it to print something that has a pointer-type value, gdb will do a reverse-lookup on that address in the symbol table of the executable and, if it finds something, will print the name of the symbol in <>.  So when you do the gdb command:

```
(gdb) print &num_accounts
$2 = (account_idx_t *) 0x7ffff767c640 <num_accounts>
```

gdb is telling you that `0x7ffff767c640` points at a symbol called `num_accounts`.  Similarly,

```
(gdb) print num_accounts_ptr
$6 = (account_idx_t *) 0x604780 <num_accounts>
```

tells you `0x604780` points at a symbol that is also called `num_accounts`.

Now the question is how you got two symbols with the same name.  The large address `0x7ffff767c640` is going to be in a shared library, as shared libraries load at addresses like that.  The small address `0x604780` is in the base executable.

Comment: I think what in the ouput " (num_accounts_ptr=0x604780 <num_accounts>) " GDB is saying is that num_accounts_ptr is pointing to the "num_accounts", which is a global variable. In fact, I am passing as a parameter the global variable itself. I do not need to do this because the variable is global and I can access it anywhere, but passing it in a parameter is valid too. I do not have duplicated symbols, otherwise I wouldn't be able to link

Comment: Duplicate symbols between a shared lib and an executable will not prevent linking unless you specifically request it with the appropriate linking flags.  Try running nm on both your executable and shared library and seeing which symbols are defined in each.