# can I declare a global variable in a shared library?

Tags: c

Can I declare a global variable inside a library that is later compiled into a shared object ? Is it safe to reference it from other libraries or the main application code by declaring it as extern?

In theory it works:

```
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ cat libcode.c 
int variable;   // <-- this is a global variable declared in a Library

void set_var(int value) {
    variable=value;
}
int get_var(void) {
    return variable;
}
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gcc -g -fPIC -c libcode.c 
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gcc -o libcode.so -shared libcode.o
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ cat appcode.c 
#include <stdio.h>
// simplified .h declarations:
extern int variable;
void set_var(int value);
int get_var(void);

void main(void) {

    set_var(44);
    printf("var=%d\n",variable);
    variable=33;
    int var_copy=get_var();
    printf("var_copy=%d\n",var_copy);
}
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gcc -g -o app -L./ -lcode appcode.c 
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ ./app
var=44
var_copy=33
[niko@dev1 snippets]$
```

Lets review it with the debugger:

```
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gdb ./app
.....
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40077e: file appcode.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/deptrack/depserv/snippets/app 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.22-16.fc23.x86_64

Breakpoint 1, main () at appcode.c:9
9       set_var(44);
(gdb) print &variable
$1 = (int *) 0x601044 <variable>
(gdb) s
set_var (value=44) at libcode.c:4
4       variable=value;
(gdb) s
5   }
(gdb) s
main () at appcode.c:10
10      printf("var=%d\n",variable);
(gdb) s
var=44
11      variable=33;
(gdb) s
12      int var_copy=get_var();
(gdb) s
get_var () at libcode.c:7
7       return variable;
(gdb) s
8   }
(gdb) s
main () at appcode.c:13
13      printf("var_copy=%d\n",var_copy);
(gdb) s
var_copy=33
14  }
(gdb) s
0x00007ffff7839580 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 28380) exited with code 014]
(gdb)
```

I say "in theory" it works because when using this approach in a large project I ran into a bug where the referencing such variable gave me unexpected results. The address of the variable was unusually high (0x7ffff767c640) and the only fix was to do declare all global variables inside main application code and use 'extern' to reference them in the code of the library. However, this way, the library could not have variables on its own. See this question for details: [getting incorrect address of a variable during a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360722/getting-incorrect-address-of-a-variable-during-a-function-call)

Comment: The unusually high addresses comes from the fact that the address is resolved dynamically as soon as the program loads. It does not necessarily mean that the address is "wrong" or points to "garbage". If you want to validate, you can `cat /proc/<pidofprogram>/maps` and search for the shared library, and whether the address is in thats libraries map range. Notice that the address of `__libc_start_main` of `libc.so.6` is also in that high address range. Most probably your system loads shared libraries starting from the end of the virtual address range (48bits in 64bit x86).

Comment: Notice that the address of global vars referenced by the program also depends on whether the program itself is position independent or not: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91672fc91ebb37ec .

Comment: I *think* that the first program's `variable` is referenced by the global offset table and indirectly resolves to the library's variable. The second program is position dependent. I think what happens is that the variable then is in the program's own data segment, and when the library loads, it copies the initial variable's value (in this case there's none, though) into that address (copy relocation) and uses the program's data segment for this variable.

Comment: I have extended the coliru with a list of relocations for the PIC and non-PIC executable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d49ea586fdff431b . You will notice a `0000000000600b90 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  variable` relocation which says "find symbol 'variable' in the shared libraries and put its address at 0x600b90". For the non-PIC case, there's a `0000000000600bc0 R_X86_64_COPY     variable` relocation which says "find 'variable' and put its value into `0x600bc0`". Of course, in that case the printf at the end of main is gibberish.

Comment: Johannes Schaub's comments help me a lot, and I finally found another blog post that explains copy relocations in detail: http://maskray.me/blog/2021-01-09-x86-copy-relocations-protected-symbols, hope it can help ones who happen to have the same problem.

Answer (score 22):

Shared libraries are not a C concept.  The shared library implementations of different operating systems and computing platforms, where they exist, exhibit differences in form and behavior.

Nevertheless, yes, all shared library implementations of which I am aware do support variables with, from a C perspective, static storage duration and external linkage, which I assume is what you mean by "global".  Inasmuch as you appear to be using Linux, your shared libraries will be of the ELF flavor.  In that case, each process that dynamically links the shared library will get its own copy of such variables.

The large variable address you describe is of no particular consequence.  ELF shared libraries do not have to be loaded at any particular address, and in fact Linux implements ASLR, which actively makes library load addresses vary.  Your shared library can be loaded more or less anywhere in your system's 64-bit virtual address space, so you really can't read much into the fact that the variable's address is numerically large.

---

As for the bug you describe, I'm inclined to think it arose from bad code, not (directly) from the involvement of a shared library.  From your description, I suspect that you ended up with multiple variables with the same name, all with external linkage.  That's an error with static linking, but in that case the compiler can (and older versions of GCC do by default) merge the duplicate variables instead of rejecting the code.

With ELF, on the other hand, it's ok for the same symbol to be defined in multiple shared objects linked into the same process, and different definitions can be referenced from different points in the overall process.  Since a shared library is compiled separately from the main program, the compiler does not have an opportunity to merge symbols, and it's not obvious that it should even if it could.  But multiple declarations of a given symbol is a *possibility* not a *necessity*.  If it happens, it's probably because your headers declare the variable wrongly.

There may be many declarations of any given variable in a program, but there must be exactly one definition.  The declarations typically come from a header file, and they should look like this:

```
extern int foo;
```

The `extern` is **mandatory** if the header is to be used in more than one source file -- that and the absence of an initializer establish that the declaration cannot be interpreted as a definition.  There should then be a definition of the variable in exactly one source file, looking something like this:

```
int foo = 0;
```

The presence of an initializer establishes that the declaration is also a definition.  It might still be a definition if the initializer were omitted, as long as the `extern` qualifier is not included, but if you don't want to learn all the details then it's safe to just provide an initializer.

A problem such as you describe will arise if there are definitions of `foo` in multiple shared objects.  That would happen if, for example, a header file contained a declaration of either of these forms:

#### bad.h

```
int foo;             /* WRONG - without extern, this is a tentative definition */
extern int bar = 0;  /* WRONG - because of the initializer, this is a definition */
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, libraries can contain global variables.

But depending on compiler/linker options, they might be not visible.  E.g. it is common practice, that libraries are built with `-fvisibility=hidden` and that only certain symbols are exported (by linker map or explicit `__attribute__((__visibility__))` tags).

Your "large" project has been probably built in such a way.

The high address might also indicate, that `variable` is some kind of other symbol (function) in another library.

Comment: No. If the visibility of that variable is hidden, the app program can't even build, reporting undefined symbol error.

I came across this same issue, and found the reason is just like what 
Johannes Schaub said, the app code should be built position independently to use variables defined in share libs.